# Restricting mappers and reducers in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapper

I am working on a security project that needs to restrict the access of mappers and reducers. 
Say in wordcount example, I have 5 files. I group 3 of the files as group 1 and 2 remaining files as group 2. All the group1 files should go to the same node in the cluster and all the group 2 files should go the same node. How can I do this? 
 
I started looking at source code but couldn't understand where to start. Any suggestions on how to do this or where to get started would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MultipleInputs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html).

For set 1 you can do something like.

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,'file/path',FileInputFormatClass,Mapper1.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,'file1/path',File1InputFormatClass,Mapper1.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,'file2/path',File2InputFormatClass,Mapper1.class);
```

For set 2

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,'file3/path',File3InputFormatClass,Mapper2.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job,'file4/path',File4InputFormatClass,Mapper2.class);
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear before but by mapper I meant a node in the cluster, not mapper class. All files in set1 should go to the same node and all files in set2 should go to the same node.